# How to preprocess individual source file with several #include files spread across in large project?

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

For getting a preprocessed output, following command is used:

```
g++ -E a.cpp > temp.cpp
```

If `a.cpp` has `#include` files not in the same folder, then we use:

```
g++ -I <directory> -E a.cpp > temp.cpp
```

Now, there are several `.cpp` file for which I want a preprocessed output.
Also a huge `#include` dependency for every .cpp file and the header file is spread in several different subdirectories; so following option is very cumbersome:

```
g++ -I <dir1> -I <dir2> -I <dir3> ... -E a.cpp > temp.cpp
```

Is there any simpler way (preferably without the use of `Makefile`) ?
(Assume that `dir1, dir2, ...` are under a single directory)

Answer (score 3):

You need the same set of `-I` for preprocessing and for compiling.

When you actually compile the code, you surely use some set of `-I` parameters (probably generated by a make file).
So just use the same (or compile, and copy&paste the `-I` parameters).

The only alternative I see is restructuring your header directories to be in a common directory (with sub-directories, using `#include <subdir/header.h>`).
But this is much more work (though it may be worth the effort).

Answer (score 0):

One way can be that you give the TOP directory in which all the subdirectory resides. This way you wont have to give many -I. But this will slowdown it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me. e.g. `g++ -I /home/mydir/ -E /home/mycode/a.cpp > temp.cpp`. I also tried `-I /home/mydir/*`, but no luck. Can you give an exact example command ?

Comment: `#include` doesn't search sub-directories. Using `-I /home/a` and `#include <x.h>` won't find `/home/a/b/x.h`. `-I /home/mydir/*` doesn't work because the shell expands it to `-I /home/mydir/a /home/mydir/b ...`, without repeating the `-I`.